# django /admin not found

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I try to setup **Nginx+Gunicorn** and when I go by my URL the **Nginx** redirects request to my app and handles it by itsels for static resource (`static` folder). Below my Nginx domain config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name asknow.local www.asknow.local;

        root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /static/ {
                root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;
        }
        location = / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/asknow.sock;
        }
}
```

The problem that I need to **Nginx** handles request by itself for `static` only (`www.asknow.local/static`) but it tries to handle other URLs too. So when I go to `www.asknow.local/admin` now **Nginx** tries to find a resource by path (`my_project/admin`).

**Nginx log**

```
2017/11/01 04:27:22 [error] 13451#13451: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/img/search.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: asknow.local, request: "GET /static/img/search.svg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.asknow.local"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: seems a default server{} config is winning over your config setup.. take a look

Comment: @Mike, I am a noobie in Nginx.... How to fix it? I removed link to default configuration in `/etc/nginx/site-enabled` and reloaded Nginx configuration but it doesn't help.

Comment: did you restart nginx?

Answer (score 2):

*Remove equal sign (=)* from

```
location = / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow     /asknow.sock;
```

}

remove the  "=" from "= /"

Basically you only matched the home page for this location block so only request going for "/" will be sent to the django. Because of this "/admin" will **not** be sent to the proxy / django. 
I got into the exact same problem as you and you were the only question relevant to it. Hopes this help you and subsequent people to encounter the same problem as me :)

**For time travelers from the future whose "django is working, url are being redirected but cannot display the page; this page might help you**